# How to pass the cloudwatch target input as a parameter to Lambda function

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

I added a cloudwatch event target input in the json format

{ "config": us}

And I tried to get this event as a input in my Lambda function as

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):

      con = event['config']
```

But this is not working , actually when I print just event , I am not getting any values

I tried   con = event.config

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):

    con = event.config
    con1 = event['config']
    print (con)
    print (con1)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work:

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):

    con1 = event['config']
    print (con1)
```

Maybe the problem is that `{ "config": us}` is not a valid json. Try with `{ "config": "us"}`

Comment: Thanks , that fixed the issue